# SQL Query Not Performing As Expected

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display 4 columns of data on a page. Each row is info from databases (3) and each artist id only has one row displayed (GROUP BY)

The problem is in row 4, that of the “last data entry per row”. It only returns the first entry. This is true for every artist id.

Example:- artist id 31 has 7 rows in the album image database each with a different timestamp.
So the output is artist image (col 1) artist name (col 2) number of albums (col 3 [Count] and last entry date (col 4). That is - pic - ACDC - 7 - 20th June 2012 (THIS SHOULD BE 6th September 2014)

Have tried many permutations of the function but cannot fix. Have run sql query separately but can only get part satisfactory result if I remove GROUP BY and COUNT. But that defeats the objective.

Many thanks

function
——————

```
<?php
function paged_artist($artist_id) {
$artists = array();
$per_page = 10;
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT Count(`artist_id`) FROM `artists`");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);
$page =(isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$artists_query = mysql_query("
SELECT `artists`.`artist_id`, `artists`.`artist_name`, LEFT(`artists`.`artist_description`, 50) as `artist_description`, `album_images`.`timestamp`, `artist_images`.`image_artist_id`, `artist_images`.`artist_name`, `artist_images`.`ext`, COUNT(`album_images`.`image_album_id`) as `image_count`
FROM `artists`
LEFT JOIN `artist_images`
ON `artists`.`artist_id` = `artist_images`.`artist_id`
LEFT JOIN `album_images`
ON `artists`.`artist_id` = `album_images`.`artist_id`
WHERE `artists`.`member_id` = ".$_SESSION['member_id']."
GROUP BY `artists`.`artist_id`
ORDER BY `artists`.`artist_name`, `album`.`timestamp` DESC
LIMIT $start, $per_page
");

While ($artists_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($artists_query)) {
$artists[] = array(
'artist_id'              => $artists_row['artist_id'],
'artist_name'            => $artists_row['artist_name'],
'artist_description'     => $artists_row['artist_description']
'timestamp'              => $artists_row['timestamp'],
'image_artist_id'        => $artists_row['image_artist_id'],
‘ext'                    => $artists_row['ext'],
'count'                  => $artists_row['image_count']
 );
}
return $artists;
}
```

Output.php
———————

```
<?php
$artists = paged_artist($artist_id);
if (empty($artists)) {
echo '<p>You Don\'t Have Any Albums</p>';
}else{
foreach ($artists as $artist) {
echo '
<tr>
<td class="alt2" align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="members_artists.php?artist_id=', $artist['artist_id'], '">
<img class="album_cover2" src="images/artists/thumbs/', $artist['artist_id'], '/',   $artist['image_artist_id'], '.', $artist['ext'], '" alt="" height="100" width="100" border="0" ></a>
</td>
<td class="alt1" valign="middle">
<a href="members_artist.php?artist_id=', $artist['artist_id'], '"><strong>', $artist['artist_name'], '</strong></a>
<div class="smallfont"></div>
</td>
<td class="alt2" align="center" valign="middle">', $artist['count'], '</td>
<td class="alt1" align="center" valign="middle">', date('dS F Y $artist['timestamp']), '
<span class="time"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</td>
</tr>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this an SQL issue? (i.e. if you simply run the SQL in some tool, do you get the problem?) Or is it only a problem when used within your PHP code?

Comment: As already mentioned I have run the query separately (using sequel pro) and do not get correct result.

Comment: [SOLVED] A little more work and I found that using the max function on the album_image.timestamp data got it to work.